# How to listen for events on Anychart vertical or horizontal lines?

Tags: javascript, anychart

I'm trying to listen for events on the vertical and horizontal lines when they're clicked or dragged.
This isn't working -

```
const controller = plot.annotations()
const verticalLine = controller.verticalLine({
  xAnchor: '2017-06-13'
})
verticalLine.listen('click', () => console.log('do something'))
```

Can't even listen to events after render using addEventListener either; only certain events like mousedown, mousemove etc. fires on the svg path.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When working with annotations, the following events can be handled:

- annotationDrawingFinish - Event type for the annotation drawing
  finish;
- annotationSelect - Event type for the annotation select;
- annotationUnselect - Event type for the annotation unselect.

You can handle the 'annotationSelect', like

```
chart.listen("annotationSelect", function(e){
})
```

See the [Drawing](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Drawing_Tools_and_Annotations/Drawing) article for more information.